# Error message: 'OfType' is not a member of 'System.Text

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, linq, visual-studio-2010

Well the full error is

```
Error 3 'OfType' is not a member of 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection'
```

in the following lines of code, (curly braces in **regex.Matches(input).OfType**)

```
For Each group As Object In regex.Matches(input).OfType(Of Match)().Select(Function(c) c.Value.ToLowerInvariant()).Where(Function(c) Not keywords.Contains(c)).GroupBy(Function(c) c).OrderByDescending(Function(c) c.Count()).ThenBy(Function(c) c.Key)
  Console.WriteLine(group.Key)
Next
```

What i do not get is why this one is working properly on VS2008 but does not in VS2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you're referencing or `Imports System.Linq` in the code under VS2010?

Answer (score 1):

`OfType` is an extension method in [System.Linq.Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx), defined in the `System.Core` assembly. (System.Core.dll)

You'll need a reference to the `System.Core` assembly and you'll need to import (`Imports` in VB and `using` in C#) the `System.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import `System.Linq`

```
imports System.Linq
```